# How does the ports package build system work?

Tags: package-management, bsd-ports

I have used yum and apt for package management. The ports system which is in use in *BSD is new to me. I see that some Linux distributions also use it. Like the Gentoo portage and Arch's ABS. I would like to know how they work? A comparison with apt or yum would be good to have.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article which compares the various package management systems.

- [Comparison of major Linux package management systems](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/comparison-of-major-linux-package-management-systems)

The article compares the following systems:

- [apt](http://wiki.debian.org/Apt)
- [aptitude](http://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude)
- [yum](http://yum.baseurl.org/)
- [pacman](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/)
- [portage](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/portage/)
- [ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/article.html#software)

Comment: The link provided shows how to use different package management systems., which is not what i am looking for. I am looking for how they differ in the way each of them work.